How to Perform OTA Update on ATSAM4 via ESP32 Rainmaker without Flashing to ESP32
I am currently working on a project where I have an ESP32 module integrated with an ATSAM4 microcontroller. I am utilizing ESP Rainmaker for managing the ESP32. My objective is to update the firmware of the ATSAM4 through an OTA (Over-the-Air) update initiated by the ESP32. Specifically, I need the ESP32 to download the OTA update file for the ATSAM4 and pass it along without flashing the ESP32 itself. How can I achieve this? What steps should I follow to intercept the OTA content meant for ATSAM4 using the ESP32, and then redirect it appropriately?
I have reviewed the Espressif documentation, but I was unable to find an answer to my question
